# USB device timeouts when trying libusb libusb_interrupt_transfer

Tags: usb, libusb

I'm trying to read data from a [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) which outputs Megatec strings. I open it with libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid() all right, and then I issue control statements with libusb_control_transfer:

- LIBUSB_REQUEST_GET_DESCRIPTOR with 0x100 that gets me the device
- LIBUSB_REQUEST_GET_DESCRIPTOR with 0x200 that gets me the interface (1) and 2 endpoints, one for input, interrupt, and one for output, interrupt.

Then I select the first interface with LIBUSB_REQUEST_SET_INTERFACE, then set the first configuration with LIBUSB_REQUEST_SET_CONFIGURATION.

So far all right. The problem starts when I use libusb_interrupt_transfer() to send or get data from the device.

- When I use the output endpoint to get bytes, nine null bytes are returned periodically. The UPS is supposed to reply with the Megatec status string.
- When I attempt to write to the input endpoint, the function never returns (or, If i specify a timeout, it timeouts).

It seems that the device is not just yet "ready" to accept data? Or, should I send the data another way?

Do I have to follow a specific format for the data I want to send?

I have checked [this one](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_3.htm), and it seems that I have to send a specific packet. But isn't it weird that the raw send doesn't fail, but it timeouts?